# How to get Price Sets related to a Contribution Page using API 4

Tags: contribution-page, price-sets, apiv4

I am trying to use the API 4 to get all the related Price Sets for a given Contribution Page. I am having a hard time with this, being new to the API and the join function. Any help? In API 3, Price Sets were returned with a list of related entities, and I was able to go through all of them to identify those related to the Contribution Page.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to get the price set used for the contribution or event page. The link is stored in civicrm_price_set_entity, with entity_table set as civicrm_contribution_page or civicrm_event and entity_id as contribution page or event id.

Or you can apply the patch to support for [api3](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23695) and [api4](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23694)